# combine output from many containers in c++

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm not very familiar with iterators in C++. Basically I have a container, which was written by someone else, which I do populate with records (I create many containers). However, I need to output tuples, instead each container separately as e.g.:

a1 | a2 | ... | an

given that each a's belong to separate containers. I will take as an e.g., a vector container:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator iter;

v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);

for (iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
  cout << (*iter) << endl;
```

The code above will output records only from one containers, but I need to combine output from many containers (all the same length), how would I go on constructing tuples from all of them?

thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to pmr's answer and your comment thereon seeking a pointer towards implementation, the basic idea for a "zipping" iterator is easy to realise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Zip
{
    Zip(const T& t, const U& u, char sep = '|')
      : it_(t.begin()), iu_(u.begin()), te_(t.end()), ue_(u.end()), sep_(sep)
    { }

    Zip& operator*() const { return *this; }

    Zip& operator++() { ++it_; ++iu_; return *this; }

    operator bool() const { return it_ != te_ && iu_ != ue_; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Zip& z)
    {
        return os << *z.it_ << z.sep_ << *z.iu_;
    }

  private:
    typename T::const_iterator it_, te_;
    typename U::const_iterator iu_, ue_;
    char sep_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    std::vector<std::string> v2;
    v2.push_back("one");
    v2.push_back("two");
    v2.push_back("three");
    v2.push_back("four");

    for (Zip<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string> > zip(v1, v2); zip; ++zip)
        std::cout << zip << '\n';
}
```

You could create a Zip iterator with one/both sides being a Zip iterator to handle more (than 2) iterators, or generalise the above using variadic templates.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is using Boost already, you could use [zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

You can also try to implement a simpler version of it (the full implementation is quite complicated).

Comment: no, I dont use boost, and I don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: @NikKovac Well, than you can give a special case implementation a try. Do you have at least C++11 for std::tuple?

Comment: how do I go on implementing this?

Comment: @NikKovac Please see the other answers. They give very good pointers toward implementing a minimal version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indices`, if container supports `random-access`, for example

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << v[i] << " " << v1[i] << endl;
}
```

You can use many iterators

```
vector<int>::iterator iter1;
for (iter = v.begin(), iter1 = v1.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter, ++iter1)
{
   cout << *iter << " " << *iter1 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> v;
set<float> v2;
vector<int>::iterator iter;
set<float>::iterator iter2;

for (iter = v.begin(), iter2 = v2.begin(); 
           iter != v.end() && iter2 != v2.end();
           ++iter, ++iter2)
  cout << (*iter) << (*iter2) << endl;
```

Keep in mind that this loop iterates **at most as much as the length of the smallest container**.

Comment: hmm this version is actually what I'm using, but is not elegant. I have many containers, and this means too many interators, making the code ugly.

Comment: @NikKovac It actually depends what your final intent is. This is a general soulution. And you are right it is ugly. I agree with that :) but maybe you can buildup on it somehow.